# Croogo Plugin Load Order

Tags: croogo

I am having trouble understanding the Croogo plugin load order.  I would like plugin "Ckeditor" to load after plugin "Facebook"

In facebook's plugin.json:

```
{
  "name": "Facebook",
  "description": "Facebook plugin for demonstrating hook system",

  "author": "Author Name",
  "authorEmail": "author@facebook.com",
  "authorUrl": "http://facebook.com",

  "dependencies": {
    "plugins": [
      "Ckeditor",
      "acl",
      "extensions"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I deactivate and reactivate facebook to get the updated plugin.json read.

Ckeditor continues to load before facebook.

Can anyone help me in changing croogo plugin load order?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The load order is 'persisted' in the settings.json (and also in the `settings` table) under the `Hook.bootstraps` key.

You can manually force the order by using the Settings shell.  Checkout the [documentation](http://docs.croogo.org/1.5/en/developers/shells.html#settings-shell).

```
# inspect current value
$ Console/cake settings.settings read Hook.bootstraps

Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : croogo
Path: /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Settings: 

    Hook.bootstraps               : Settings,Comments,Contacts,Nodes,Meta,Menus,Users,Blocks,Taxonomy,FileManager,Ckeditor,Wysiwyg

# set a new value
$ Console/cake settings.settings write Hook.bootstraps Settings,Ckeditor,Comments,Contacts,Nodes,Meta,Menus,Users,Blocks,Taxonomy,FileManager,Wysiwyg

Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : croogo
Path: /home/rachman/work/personal/deploy/croogo/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Updating Hook.bootstraps

- Settings,Comments,Contacts,Nodes,Meta,Menus,Users,Blocks,Taxonomy,FileManager,Ckeditor,Wysiwyg
+ Settings,Ckeditor,Comments,Contacts,Nodes,Meta,Menus,Users,Blocks,Taxonomy,FileManager,Wysiwyg
Confirm update (y/n) 
[n] > y
Setting updated
```